# C# Visual Studio post form going to different route

Tags: c#, forms, http-post

I have this form in `RetrievePassword.cshtml`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendPassword", "Users", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
}
```

With this in my UsersController:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult RetrievePassword() 
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendPassword(string email)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SendPassword POST");
    return null;
}
```

But, when I click the submit button in the form, the webpage tries to navigate to /Accounts/Login with the URL being `localhost:58893/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%fUsers%2SendPassword`. An account controller exists but there is no login method. However, I get the correct `Users/SendPassword` URL when if I remove the SendPassword method in the Users Controller, but of course nothing shows up since there is no method or view attached.

Any ideas to why it tries to navigate to `Account/Login` instead of `Users/SendPassword`? OR why the URL is correct only if I remove the method in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SendPassword Action does not include the [AllowAnonymous] attribute like the one above does.

Due to your current set up, ASP.NET is trying to authenticate you by sending you to the Account/Login route.

If you need the ability to POST to the SendPassword action without being authenticated, add the [AllowAnonymous] attribute to it as well like so:

```
[AllowAnonymous, HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendPassword(string email)
```